# Uncaught Error: Module "events" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "events.EventEmitter" in client code

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, vite

I don't know what's going on I am making a frontend using vite + react for my mern project and suddenly starts encountering this error.

```
Error: Module "events" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "events.EventEmitter" in client code.
```

git repo link : https://github.com/Gaurav200247/E-Book-Store-Mern-Project

Comment: Hi! Could you figure it out? I'm stuck with the same issue.

Comment: not able to figure it out, but i'm using localstorage (JS) in my code i just removed that lines of code. The error gone automatically.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, the `events` module was in sub-dependencies, I added it manually by `npm install events`, then the issue disappeared.

Comment: Did you import anything afterwards?

Comment: No, it couldn't find that module somewhere inside of a dependency. After manual installation that becomes available.

Comment: for me error is not resolved even after installing events , with `npm i events`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

1. You are importing the correct library in your code.
2. The library you are attempting to use is directly installed in your project, libraries available as sub-dependencies will not work.

Answer (score 0):

it happens when mistakenly a backend package gets imported in frontend

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).